# Exception Handler of ControllerAdvice Not working in Rest API Get Request using Spring Boot. How to resolve?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, exception

I have a Rest Controller using Spring Boot

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class TeamController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/getmember/{memberId}",method = {RequestMethod.GET})
    public ResponseEntity<TeamMember> findmember(@PathVariable("memberId") int theId){
        
        TeamMember teamMember = teamService.findMember(theId);
        if( null == teamMember) {
            throw new TeamMemberNotFoundException();
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<TeamMember>(teamMember,HttpStatus.OK);
        
    }
```

My Exception Class

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, reason = "Member not found")
public class TeamMemberNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {

// constructor

}
```

My Global Exception Handler annotated using @ControllerAdvice

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class TeamMemberNotFoundExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    
    
    @ExceptionHandler(TeamMemberNotFoundException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<TeamMemberNotFoundErrorResponse> handleException(TeamMemberNotFoundException e) {

        TeamMemberNotFoundErrorResponse t = new TeamMemberNotFoundErrorResponse(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value(),"Dude he doesnt exist wake up",System.currentTimeMillis());
        
        return new ResponseEntity<TeamMemberNotFoundErrorResponse>(t, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);

    }
     
    
}
```

When Im using the Exception Handler code inside the controller directly it seems to work but the Exception Handler when used in the Class annotated with @Controller Advice is not called at all and I get default 500 Internal Server error. I have attached picture of my project directory structure. Im trying hard but unable to resolve this

[My project directory strcuture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f17mN.png)

Answer (score 0):

This may happen because spring uses convention over configuration if you don't specify. One of the packages spring checks is the "exception" package, try putting your ControllerAdvice there. If it doesn't work, try specifying the package of your ControlerAdvice in your Application class.

Comment: I made another sample project just to check if global exception handler from controller advice works, without any database operation using Postman, If I got "1" as a parameter from request URI , I threw a custom exception from the controller and the global ControllerAdvice (having an exception handler) which was in a different package (not in the same package as exception or controller but yes the child package of the Application class). This time it worked. I guess the other project had some directory or issue detecting the controller advice